# OnClick event not running

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have this function:

```
protected void register(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    db_connection();
    try
    {
        string emailAddress = emailReg.Text.ToString();
        string passwordR = passwordReg.Text.ToString();
        string firstName = forename.Text.ToString();
        string lastName = surname.Text.ToString();
        string telephoneV = telephone.Text.ToString();
        string addressV = address.Text.ToString();
        string address2V = address2.Text.ToString();
        string countyV = county.Text.ToString();
        string postcodeV = postcode.Text.ToString();
        string countryV = country.Text.ToString();
        //converts data submitted to form into variables

        var cmd = new MySqlCommand();

        cmd.CommandText = "insert into mydb1.address values(null,'" + addressV.ToString() + "','" + address2V + "','" + countyV + "','" + postcodeV + "','" + countryV + "')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //above sql statements insert variables into the database

        long id1 = cmd.LastInsertedId;

        cmd.CommandText = "insert into mydb1.person values(null,'" + firstName.ToString() + "','" + lastName + "','" + telephoneV + "','" + emailAddress + "','" + id1 + "','" + passwordR + "')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        connect.Dispose(); //removes any stored data that is no longer needed
        connect.Close(); //closes the connection to the database

        Response.Redirect("myAccount.aspx");
    }
```

This is supposed to update my database with details a user entered into the form, however the page just refreshes when the button is clicked and doesn't seem to add to the database. Am I wrong to be using a try?

Edit: here is the .aspx code

```
<div class="registerWrapper">

    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID ="emailReg" runat="server" placeholder="Email"></asp:TextBox><br/>
    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="passwordReg" TextMode="Password" runat="server" placeholder="Password"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="forename" runat="server" placeholder="First Name"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="surname" runat="server" placeholder="Surname"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="telephone" runat="server" placeholder="Telephone"></asp:TextBox><br />

    <div class="nextButton btn btn-primary">
            Next 
    </div>
</div><!-- /addressWrapper -->



<div class="addressWrapper">
    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID ="address" runat="server" placeholder="Address - Line 1"></asp:TextBox><br/>
    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="address2" runat="server" placeholder="Line 2"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="county" runat="server" placeholder="County"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="postcode" runat="server" placeholder="Postcode"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="country" runat="server" placeholder="Country"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-primary" ID="loginButton" runat="server" text="Submit" OnCLick="register"></asp:Button>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is open for sql injection attack. Don't use single quotes. Always use parameters

Comment: Share the client side code.

Comment: As a side note, you're extremely open to SQL injection by not parameterizing your code. Take a look at: https://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter for an example.

Comment: @Ullas this is just a site for my apprenticeship, so i'm not to concerned with safety precations right now as long as it works correctly.

Comment: show button markup

Comment: @Kumar_Vikas what do you mean by client side code? My asp form?

Comment: what is meaning of null in your insert statement for first column value?

Comment: I guess you are passing null for ID column which you have set as Identity and you are passing it as null so might that cause an issue in insert statement can you check by putting debugger.

Comment: it is an ID which auto increments so null just bumps it up to the next value

Comment: So try by removing that null from insert statement that causes issue.

Comment: I've had this code working previously with the null in there, I'm certain this isn't causing the issue

Comment: can you please post your aspx page code here.

Comment: have added a section of my aspx code

Comment: can u remove try catch block. maybe has exception

Comment: @LucasTeixeira indeed it is.

Comment: @levent I have an empty catch currently.

Comment: can u add `throw;` to catch.

Comment: ah, the error was 'the connection must be valid and open' do i need to add the connection string to my sql statements?

Comment: You missed cmd.Connection = con //Connection object name and also you have to open connection

Comment: I've opened the connection by calling the function 'db_connection();' which includes all the connection setup etc.

Comment: Connection is openeed but you missed to set Connection property of cmd. set connection object to cmd by cmd.Connection = con

Comment: right got that so do i just need to reference con in my command?

Comment: Yes only that you were missing in your code and also we did not recognized at first.